# How change regular expression on http/https?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use a regular expression to get all SRC paths in HTML code.

```
'/src="http?:\/\/[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i'
```

How I can add https to expression?

I tried:

```
 '/src="http|https?:\/\/[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `s` next to `p` in `http` and make it as optional by adding the quantfier `?` next to the `s`

```
'/src="https?:\/\/[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i'
```

`http?` in your regex makes `p` as optional. Don't do that.

If you want to make the whole `http://` or `https://` as optional, you need to put them inside a capturing or non-capturing group and then make it as optional by adding the quantifier `?` next to that added group.

```
'/src="(?:https?:\/\/)?[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/src="(?:http|https)?:\/\/[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i'
```

Try this.Use this if `http or https` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('#src="([^"]*)"#i', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Remarks:**

- A lot of people enclose the regexps in forward slashes (`/`) and then quote all the slashes that appear in the regexp. In `PHP` the forward slashes are not mandatory, [other characters can be used as delimiters as well](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). When you want to parse URLs you better use something else as delimiter (`~` for example, is very good for URLs) and the regexp will become easier to read because the forward slashes do not need to be quoted any more.
- The question says: `use a regular expression to get all SRC paths in HTML code`. Not all the URLs start with `http://` or `https://`. There are also `ftp://`, `mailto:`, `data:` and others. More, even if you want only the `http` or `https` URLs, in HTML they can be expressed as relative to the current document (i.e. something like `src="image1.jpg"`) or current host (`src="/images/2.jpg"`). All these are extracted by the code above. Run through the list, check the first characters of each result (to find out if they are absolute or relative), calculate the complete URLs from relative URLs and keep only what you need (probably only `http://` and `https://`).